# Javascript Removing an Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am working on an image uploader and below is a preview of what I have so far:

[image]

The first image is what they first see.  Now what I want to happen, is when an image is actually uploaded (using AJAX) then I want Javascript to remove that small tag that I have, so it doesn't appear like it does in that second image.

**My HTML:**

```
<div id="upload_pics">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="upload.php">
            <input type="file" name="images" id="images" multiple />
            <button type="submit" id="btn">Upload Files!</button>
        </form>
        <small>Don't have any images yet? <a href="">Click here</a> to use a Stock Photo</small>
        <div id="response"></div>
    </div>
```

**My Javascript:**

```
if (formdata) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "upload.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (res) {
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res;
                //Remove small should go here
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#upload_pics').find('small').remove();
```

Put that in your `success` callback, will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You could also `hide` it to be able to easily `show` it at a later time if you need it.

```
$('#upload_pics small').hide();
$('#upload_pics small').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#upload_pics small').remove ();
```

That should do the job. First it [selects](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) the  element contained in the node with id upload_pics, then it [removes](http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=remove&go=) it.

By the way, you could also use jQuery to add the AJAX response to the #response element:

```
$('#response').html(res);
```

Comment: '#small' implies there's an element with id='small', which isn't the case.  To target the HTML tag, it needs to be $('small')

Comment: @duncan True, thanks! I misread the question. I just corrected the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post and took out the ID but originally the post had id="small" because I thought I could only target elements with an ID on it.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Well, in fact that's one of the great things of jQuery, the ability to use CSS selectors to target elements. Have a read at their documentation! http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=selectors

Answer (score 0):

Either set the innerHTML of that div as empty.

or use removeChild function to remove the node altogether from the DOM.